# Paralell testing for aggregate and individual variables in generalized Difference-in-Differences?

Tags: difference-in-difference

I am using a **joint null test** to test a parallel trend for satisfying the key assumption of DiD approach following [Miller, 2021](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10940-021-09513-w). In general, if the p-value of joint null test is insignificant (p-value >0.1), there is no parallel trend before the event dates.

In my sample, I have 4 variables called A,B,C,D, while A=B+C-D.

When I did the join null test as above, I saw that the A satisfies parallel but B,C,D do not satisfy. But I want to know which is the cause of movement in A among B,C,D. Is there any way for me to conduct the test on B,C,D while the parallel assumption of them being violated as mentioned?

Comment: Are these measures of crime?

Comment: @ThomasBilach . They are firm-level variables

Comment: When you say which is the “cause of movement” in A, are you referring to the movement in the post-period?

Comment: @ThomasBilach , yes, it is what I mean